# power bi date measure card

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, powerbi-desktop

I have a dashboard that needs to display the beginning of the week, on Monday, of the week that I'm in.  So for example, if its 1/7/2020, this card would show 1/6/2020.  Here is the code I was trying:

```
Report Date = CALCULATE(TODAY(), FILTER('Calendar', 'Calendar'[WeekStartDate]))
```

The column in the `Calendar` table is `Weekstartdate`, which is accurate and does show the week of 1/6/2020 with the corresponding dates to it; however, it looks like it won't filter it from today's date.

Any ideas? or advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are looking for is a single date, which gives the week start date based on Today's date, you should create a measure:

```
WeekStartMeasure = TODAY()-WEEKDAY(Today(),2)+1
```

If you are creating week start date based on a column, then you should create a column with the following calculation:

```
WeekStartDate = Table[Date]-  WEEKDAY(Table[Date],2)+1
```

Once you create the measure/column, you can use it in the visualization to get the desired result.

Comment: The latter calculation is what I was using from my previous measure formula.  In my date or calendar table it is exactly that.  I was trying to reference this column in a measure for the card in the dashboard. Anyway, I appreciate your response it is what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate this way also

```
    if (
        WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1) == 1, 
        TODAY(),
        TODAY() - (WEEKDAY(TODAY(),1) - 1)
    )
```